# Trying to execute 2 Promises before .then stuck in loop?

Tags: javascript

I think i may be executing the promises wrong but not quite sure, basically the webpage is stuck in a loop of loading or perhaps extremely slow.

```
getSummonerData(req.params.playerName)
  .then(function (summonerData) {
          getMatchIds(summonerData.id)
                .then(function (matchIds) {
                    res.render('profile', {title: 'Profile', summoner: summonerData});
                });
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you passing in a players object/array, then matching/mapping to a particular player based off their id, and then rendering some of their properties? Second are you just looking to better understand promises? If not there is a better way you can do this with the forEach and filter array methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would structure your promise string a little bit differently. Because it seems like you may be running into an issue where one of your promises is either being rejected or throwing an error and you are not catching that error. So another way rewrite that block of code to catch any unforseen errors could be:

```
var summoner;
getSummonerData(req.params.playerName)
    .then(function (summonerData) {
        summoner = summonerData;
        return getMatchIds(summonerData.id);
    })
    .then(function (matchIds) {
        res.render('profile', {title: 'Profile', summoner: summoner});
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });
```

This allows you to have one catch block that will catch any rejected promises or errors in the entire promise chain. Hope this helps!